# Performing validation in WPF (WAF Framework)

Tags: wpf, validation

I have a question about how to best perform the validation in the setup below.

I have a small WPF-based UI (using the WAF framework).  This particular dialog contains a `DecimalUpDown` control (this is from the WPF extended toolkit) in which the user may modify the value by using the up/down arrows or typing or pasting.

The user should not be allowed to continue (the Next button should be disabled) until a valid number (format and range) is supplied.  The user should also be aware that it is this field's value from preventing them to continue.  **How do I perform this validation?**

I have a pretty simple View Model -- it contains a `float FooValue` property (bound to the up/down control) and implements an `bool IsValid()` which the parent container binds to (for the `Next` button's enabled state).

[image]

I notice some other web sites suggest that I should throw an exception in the setter (e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation).  It doesn't really make sense here because my property is a `float`.  Should that instead bind to the "Text" value of the numeric up/down and do the parsing (and throwing the exception) at the View Model level?

Comment: Are you sure you mean WAF? I think you mean MEF - http://mef.codeplex.com/

Comment: 100% sure I mean WAF.  http://waf.codeplex.com/

Comment: I've only heard of WAF meaning - http://code.google.com/p/waf/ - and I think that is what the SO tag is for.

Comment: Sorry about that - I yanked the tag.  Thanks for spotting that

Comment: Also, it turns out WPF Application Framework uses MEF :)

Answer (score 0):

On waf.codeplex.com there is actually an example that shows how to do data input validations - http://www.codeplex.com/Download?ProjectName=waf&DownloadId=282750 . It is using the BookLibrary sample app which is included in the framework source code.

Basically you will be using data annotations on your properties and the `ValidatesOnDataErrors=true` attribute on your XAML elements.

Comment: Thanks for the PDF, but this case seems a bit more complex than the attributes they use.  For example, we can't get away with a compile-time const regular expression if we take localization into mind (e.g. in some locales 10.8 might be correct, in others 10,8 might be correct) etc.